# iOS Containment API Sub Controller Size

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

So I have a view controller with a toolbar at the top and a container view underneath which I've wired up as the view for the controller.

I'm then doing this:

```
[self addChildViewController:detailsView];
[self.view addSubview:detailsView.view];
[detailsView didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

For some reason, the details controller appears on top of the toolbar. Is there a way to specify the size?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Did you set up the container view in a storyboard? also, what do you mean by "wired up as the view of the controller"?

Comment: This is what I mean: http://d.pr/i/2gZW

Comment: If you've set it up in storyboard, you don't need to also add the subview / child controller in code. That's done for you via the containment segue.

Comment: Ah, so I can pass multiple controllers to the segue when the segmentedcontrol is touched?

Comment: Do you mean you want to change what controller is embedded in the container view?

Comment: Oh I think I can do something like this:

- (IBAction)segmentCtrlChanged:(id)sender {
 UISegmentedControl *seg = sender;
 if (seg.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) 
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue1" sender:self];
 else if (seg.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) 
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue2" sender:self];
}

Comment: Yes, you should be able to segue to other controllers from your embedded controller as normal, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Yes, I want to changed the embedded controller when the segmentedcontrol is touched.

Comment: Hmm, it seems there can be only one embed segue though. Any thoughts on how to do that transition to another controller when I hit a UISegmentedControl?

Comment: I suppose I could just have multiple container views, and hide/show some.

Answer (score 0):

When you set up container views in IB, you don't need to use any of the usual custom container controller code, all that is done automatically for you by IB. Also, you shouldn't change the view of the main controller (the one with the container view in it), it's view should still be the whole view that the container view is embedded in. You access the embedded controller (the one that's provided automatically (and sized to fit the container view) through the main controller's childViewControllers property.